# Отключить плагин или библиотеку при определенном разрешении

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, адаптивность

Всем привет, мне надо отключить плагин, при определенном разрешении, например при 768 пикселей и ниже. То есть у меня вот так подключен плагин <скрипт type="text/javascript" src="libs/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"> в index.html. Видел здесь 2 похожие темы, но ответы по ним не помогли, да и там советовали только скрипты как отключать и подключать, это я знаю. Здесь вопрос как путь к плагину что-ли удалять, в общем, чтобы плагин вообще не подключался при разрешении 768 и ниже. Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создавать script элемент с помощью JavaScript:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'libs/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wf4pehv/)

Можно без использования jQuery (не будет работать в старых IE):

```
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'libs/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант у меня не работает, но я решил проблему еще вчера следующим образом

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   {
   if (screen.width > 768) document.write ('<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.js" ></sc' + 'ript>');
   }
   </script>

Comment: Только проблема в том, что при ресайзе надо обновлять страницу, чтобы принялись изменения, а это не очень хорошо. ну что поделать если нет варианта по-лучше...

Comment: @LiEm Вы хотели "чтобы плагин вообще не подключался", нельзя отменить подключение плагина.

Answer (score 0):

Не может быть сделано ... Тег скрипта обрабатывается как только DOM визуализатор делает это, так что получить ссылку на него после того, как обработался ничего не даст.
Вместо этого можно удалять event и переназначать функции.

Comment: Я буду рад любому решению, главное чтобы выше 768px плагин работал а ниже данного разрешения не работал

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны будете использовать JS для этого. В зависимости от того, что Lightbox библиотеки вы используете вы, возможно, потребуется повторно инициализировать его после того, как свойство Lightbox отн добавляется обратно.

```
var lightboxOnResize = function lightboxOnResize() { if ($(window).width() < 960) { $('a[rel="lightbox"]') .removeProp('rel') .addClass('lightboxRemoved'); } else { $('a.lightboxRemoved').prop('rel', 'lightbox'); }
 }
 $(document).ready(lightboxOnResize); $(window).resize(lightboxOnResize);
```